# Aptana Eclipse Plugin and Dojo Auto Completion

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, dojo, aptana

I was just wondering if it was possible, and how I would go about and do this... I found support for [configuring it within Aptana itself](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/117-configuring-aptana-for-javascript-dojo), however I couldn't find anything that explained how to configure it within its plugin version in eclipse.  When I say dojo. all I get are auto-completed 'JS Core' functions.  Looking into aptana in eclipse's preferences didn't turn up much either.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration should be the same for both the plugin and standalone versions. The process has changed quite a bit since version 2...updated information is here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

The Dojo library support is detailed on a page linked from that one (http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support), but it's important to read the first page as that overviews how the support works in general.